# Cannot write file to App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I'm working on a pipeline which can be executed via the web. A program which is used by this pipeline requires some data files, these cannot be piped. So I first fetch the data from a database, write this to a file, and execute the program. Since the code for the pipeline is placed in the App_Code folder, I would also like to place the data files in this folder. I've set the App_Code permissions (recursively) to: rwxrwxrwx. When attempting to write to a file I get this Error:

```
Failed to acquire lock after
Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.
Stack Trace:
System.ApplicationException: Failed to acquire lock after
  at System.Web.SessionState.SessionInProcHandler.ResetItemTimeout
(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String id) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

When I execute the pipeline via the command line I don't get this error. This is possibly caused by the user which is used by each execution. But, the permission settings should prevent problems with this in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be writing anything to the App_Code folder as it's for code. You should use the App_Data folder instead.

You can get the Path to the App_Data folder using:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString()
```

Comment: Accepted, but I don't think it is explaining the cause of the error.

Comment: You're correct, I should have explained further. I'm not 100% sure if it's because you're attempting file operations in a special .net folder. Is it working now that you're using it in Add_Data?

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'm fairy sure it's because the App_Code folder is a special reserved folder in .Net. You can work with custom folders without any problems but most of the time App_Data is the correct place for it.